# http POST containing a foreign key and save it

Tags: django, database, python-3.x

I send http request post from client.
Code client.

```
import requests
payload = {'data':['12', '15'], 'timestamp':['1', '2'], 'mission':['Mission01', 'Mission01']}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", data=payload)
print(r.url)
```

I receive in Django http post:

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Mission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '-' + self.description

class SensorLog (models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import Mission, SensorLog

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    context = {'request_method': request.method}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        datas = request.POST.getlist('data')
        timestamps = request.POST.getlist('timestamp')
        missions = request.POST.getlist('mission')
        for i in range(len(datas)):
           post = SensorLog.objects.create(data=datas[i], timestamp=timestamps[i], mission=missions[i])
    return render(request, 'your_template_name_here', context)
```

If I run django and client..
In django i have error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Mission01'": "SensorLog.mission" must be a "Mission" instance.
```

why don't i save data? why have i this error?
How can i do?

Comment: Your other fields are `CharFields`, so they accept the string values that come from POST data.  But you need a way to take the mission string and convert that to a `Mission` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `SensorLog.objects.create(data=datas[i], timestamp=timestamps[i], mission=missions[i])`, the constructor is expecting a `Mission` instance, but you're providing a string.

To solve this you can either lookup the `Mission` by name before, or just pass in the id of the `Mission` and use the `mission_id` keyword arg in the `SensorLog` constructor.

Using the names (in your `home` method):

```
for i in range(len(datas)):
    mission = Mission.objects.get(name=missions[i])
    post = SensorLog.objects.create(data=datas[i], timestamp=timestamps[i], mission=mission)
```

Using ids:

```
payload = {'data':['12', '15'], 'timestamp':['1', '2'], 'mission_ids':[1, 2]}
```

Then in the `home` method:

```
for i in range(len(datas)):
    post = SensorLog.objects.create(data=datas[i], timestamp=timestamps[i], mission_id=mission_ids[i])
```